# VB.net starting a new session

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session-state, session-timeout

While Ive seen plenty of examples in PHP, can't seem to find one in VB, I want to know if this is even possible.

I have a page, a session starts on page load (using global.asax) the user may not move from (or interact with) that page for a long while and I dont want to increase the session timeout. When the session times out after say.. 20 minutes, I want to start a new one, without moving from the page.

I also don't want constant keep-alives

I want to do it via another method (timer, button press...)

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extend the session without a constant keep-alive, and prefer the user to click a button, or base it on a timer, then I would advise that you use fire an AJAX request to the server and not expect any type of a response.   Simply doing so will keep the session alive.   You can fire this request on any of your preferred criteria using javascript/jquery.